# Are digital filters example of dynamic programing?

Tags: filter, filtering, dynamic-programming

A digital filter can be represented using a discrete difference equation, for example:

```
Y[n]= k1* Y[n-1]+k2*X[n]
```

where Y[n] is the output of the filter and X[n] is the input to the filter, k1 and k2 are some constant. It's a simple first order filter. As I read about dynamic programing, it's described as a powerful technique. I am wondering if the above filter is an example of a dynamic program. Is representing a problem using recursion, the crux of dynamic programing?

Answer (score 0):

strictly speaking, this is not an example of dynamic programming

for DP, u should make some decisions at each point, eg. maximum or minimum.

in your question, there is no decision making. so it is a recurrence, but not DP